# How do I solve an equation for a voltage variable on both side, if it just cancels out?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsAS0k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is equivalent to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTya4K.png)</sup>
The goal is to find the potential difference across R1. The dependent current source produce a current of I=V*20. V is the potential difference across the gap. Since the left loop is open circuited by the gap, you can eliminate the left loop and just deal with the right loop, hence the second equivalent circuit. But the interesting thing is that the potential difference across R1 is equal to V. Or -V (I am confused here).

The difficulty is that looking at the second picture, we have the equation:$$V_x=20V_x\times 1000$$

How can I solve for Vx without cancelling it out?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, Vx is V across the gap. I, the current output by the variable current source is 20*V.

Comment: You are right,you cannot cancel Vx, but your equation does have the trivial solution Vx=0. That just means *with no input there's zero output*. Then input V1 comes into play....

Comment: Where is 'x'? It's not marked on either schematic.

Comment: Something is wrong in the enunciate of the question: I=20V is a nonsense, even if we take V as the volt unit or the variable. This mixing between the usage of "V" has the voltage at some point of the circuit and V has voltage unit appears in more points: see were it is said V1=1V and i=20V, being first one "volts" and second one "variable"?.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui simple 20 is actually a conductance, 20S.

Answer (score 1):

When reducing the circuit, you have actually made your life more difficult and stumbled. The voltage across R is not the current source control voltage \$V\$ you have presumed, if you look at the left half of the circuit it's easily seen it's actually \$1-V\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEuPIk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A correct equation to be solved goes:

$$
1-V = 1000\times20\times V
$$

Solving for \$V\$ yields \$V = 1/20001 \approx 5\times10^{-5}\$, and voltage accross resistor is \$1-V\ = 0.99995\$.

Moral of the story: do not reduce circuits beyond necessity.

Answer (score 1):

On the positive side of the gap (I'll call it Vp), the voltage is 1V.

On the negative side of the gap (I'll call it Vm), the voltage is I*1k.

I  = 20 * (Vp - Vm).

Solve for I.

Answer (score 0):

From KCL we know that:

$$I_S = \frac{V}{R1}$$

where:

$$I_S = 20S *(1V - V) = 20S *(1V - I_s*R1)  $$

Therefore

$$ 20S *(1V - I_s*R_1) = \frac{I_s*R_1}{R_1} $$

$$ 20S *(1V - I_s*1k\Omega) = \frac{I_s*1k\Omega}{1k\Omega} $$

$$ 20S *(1V - I_s*1k\Omega) = I_s $$

$$ 20* 20 000I_s  = I_s $$

And finally

$$I_s = \frac{20}{20 001} \approx 0.99995mA \approx 999.95\mu A$$

Answer (score -1):

Hints: The current 20V only passes through the 1k resistor. This gives you the voltage drop across the resistor. Apply KVL for the loop containing V1 and the resistor to find the value of V.

In your second schematic it's not clear what Vx is. If it's a different source then Vx has to be zero. But I think you're mixing V with Vx (I guess Vx is the voltage across the resistor?). Note that V is not the same as Vx. But we can solve for Vx by writing V in terms of Vx: V=V1-Vx. Now in that schematic apply KVL to find Vx: 20(V1-Vx).R1=Vx.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. V=Vx, they both are the potential difference across that gap.